# Whether to use Models in MVC or models in MVVM?

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, single-page-application

I am creating an SPA (using visual studio 2013). The application gets data from the WCF service. The data generally involves C# collection. As the SPA is MVC based, I copy the data into Model objects and pass it to the view. Now, I am planning to use Knockout.js. Should I need to directly convert the data from WCF service into JSON or copy the data to Models (in MVC) and then convert them to JSON?

P.S:
My WCF service and the SPA lie on the same system. Currently I transfer the contents from the service to the web application using binary serialization and not in JSON format.

Comment: Do you have a specific concern or block with either method?

Comment: I would like to know which one is a better pattern to proceed with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the cleanest approach here is to simply return JSON from your controllers and not have MVC views (or WCF service) at all. This way you can keep the front end completely separate and the server code generally becomes a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank you Tom..But my application demands the presence of WCF service and the MVC architecture.

Comment: Ok, but if you dont use VIEWS (.cshtml), and instead return your WCF results as JSON from the controller, you could make your life a lot easier.